# MVC dropdown list with preselected value does not allow submitting the form when the field is required

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I have a dropdown list which is populated by states. When the Update address page is loaded, the field's are already filled in and the state is selected. I added data annotation "Required" to this State field inside model, but it doesn't allow for the value to be preset. It doesn't show the message but I cannot submit the form, I need to select state in order to submit the form (reselecting I guess). How to tell the form that the preselected value is the one to validate?

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "StateRequired")]   
public string State { get; set; }
```

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.StatesList, Model.SelectedState, new { @class = "form-control form-select" })
```

`SelectedState` is a model property that has the Db value of the user's address already stored in the Db.

Comment: are you sure the "values" of the items are set?  Go into your dev options in the browser and look at the values of each state.

Comment: Good call, the selected item doesn't have value set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is the solution, @LarryBud commented pointing me to the right direction.

So basically, the selected value was not set inside the list, but somebody added that value in the place where the text "select a state" would normaly be, so the state was showing up but was not a part of the list.

I just marked user's state as selected in the list of states and it solved.

```
DDList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = row["State"].ToString(), Value = row["Abbreviation"].ToString(), Selected = true });
```